# Sample MVC3 honeypot project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, honeypot

I was wondering if anyone had an sln file for an MVC3 project containing the Honeypot anti-spam feature I could download and modify. I've tried adding honeypot to projects myself, but to no avail; I always get syntax errors.

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC or something else?

Comment: yes; a project with that feature implemented.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Honeypot MVC page](https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC), you can install the project from the NuGet package manager console - `Install-Package SimpleHoneypot.MVC`.

I'd use NuGet to install the package into an existing MVC solution rather than trying to add it by hand, as it'll pull in the references and touch up the config and whatever else it does for you.

Comment: I tried doing it that way but got syntax errors. I wound up downloading a project with the feature already installed.

Comment: @jsmith odd - I'd submit a bug report to them; it should be really trivial to reproduce an error with the installation.